# duplo for com python

Tags: python-3.x

Fiz a conexão com o banco de dados e preciso comparar duas tabelas tab1 e tab2 de forma que o "for" externo fixe a primeira linha de "tab1" na coluna zero e o "for" interno percorra todos as linhas da coluna um da tab2 assim por diante até comparar a ultima linha de tab1 com a ultima tab2 tentei montar aqui, mas não esta correto.

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=localhost;database=teste;uid=;pwd=")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from tab1')
cursor.execute('select * from tab2')
   
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row[0])
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print (row[1])
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se ainda tiver interesse em ter sua questão respondida explique detalhadamente o qual o resultado pretende obter(mostre), talvez o resultado pretendido possa ser obtido apenas com SQL.

Comment: Já falei. só explicar o que pretende fazer. Seria por exemplo, na linha 0 da tabela1 buscar os primeiros 40 alunos com idade menor ou igual a 18 anos na tabela 2, na linha 1 da tabela1 buscar os próximos(ou seria novamente os primeiros?) 20 alunos com idade menor a 18 anos na tabela 2. na linha 2 da tabela1 buscar os próximos(ou seria novamente os primeiros?) 40 alunos com idade menor a 18 anos na tabela 2,.... Ou seja eu não respondo porque não sei se quer fazer uma busca preenchendo as salas ou fazer uma busca procurando candidatos para as salas.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o ideial seria você fazer o filtro do que você está buscando já na sua consulta, e evitar o processamento do lado da aplicação. Fazendo uma comparação simples depois. Se você usar o mesmo cursor que você utilizou para armazenar a query na primeira vez vai perder o valor retornado pelo banco de dados também. Crie duas variaveis.

```
# SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TAB1 ORDER BY ID DESC

tab1 = cursor1.fetchone()
tab1 = cursor2.fetchone()
if tab1['field'] == tab2['field']:
    # definir aqui a lógica
```

Comment: Ola Leandro, boa noite. Valeu pelo retorno a ideia sua me parece melhor que a minha, mas desculpe a ignorância é que não entendi como posso varrer as tabelas e fazer as comparações atribuindo dois cursores para a "tab1" poderia por favor me explicar como isso funciona? Anexei na pergunta duas tabelas de exemplo. Obrigado

Comment: Opa, certo você vai comparar os valores dos dois cursores `tab1['nome_da_coluna']` vai obter o valor armazenado dela, quando se compara `cursor1 == cursor2` o resultado será diferente porque não estamos comparando dados e sim duas instancias.

Comment: Desculpe o transtorno, mas estou apanhando aqui pra entender algumas coisas por exemplo - como devo declarar os dois cursores apontando pra mesma consulta? como devo armazenar o conteúdo da tab2 tenho que criar um terceiro cursor? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Capacity:
    def __init__(self, cod_sala, capacidade, idade):
        self.cod_sale = cod_sala
        self.capacidade = capacidade
        self.idade = idade
        self.students = []



import pyodbc
import re
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=localhost;database=teste;uid=;pwd=")

cursor1 = conn.cursor()
cursor2 = conn.cursor()

cursor1.execute('select * from tab1')
cursor2.execute('select * from tab2')

class_capacity = []

for row in cursor1.fetchall():
    class_capacity.append(Capacity(row['cod_sale'], row['capacidade'], row['idade']))

for row2 in cursor2.fetchall():
    for cc in class_capacity:
        extract = cc.idade.split('1')
        value = '1' + extract[1]
        condition = extract[0]
    ....
```

Comment: Ola Leandro, boa tarde. Este código retorna o erro: Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Conexão ocupada com os resultados de outro HSTMT (0) (SQLExecDirectW)') - está passando dois cursores na mesma conexão.